# python loop in parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I'd like to do something like this:

```
for entry in catalog:
    do some operation
```

Each entry is not necessarily of equal load, but since there are thousands of entries, I'm guessing breaking them down into, say, a thousand will more or less even things out.
So I'd like to run multiple processes, each for a chunk of entries to shorten my overall run time.

I have tried something like the following for 100 of them:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
p1 = Process(target=myfunc, kwargs=dict(start=0, end=50))
p2 = Process(target=myfunc, kwargs=dict(start=50, end=100))
p1.start()
p2.start()
```

From the logging of the script, it seems like the two processes indeed runs at the same time, but compared to processing all 100 in serial, runtime is only 20% reduced.
Is this to be expected? Is there a better way to break down a large loop operation in python?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do things in parallel... well, you have to run them in parallel.  I think the reason why you're only seeing a 20% speed boost is because of the cost of creating and joining processes is quite high and chewing into the performance benefit you get from multiprocessing.  This degraded speed increase is to be expected, since there is a cost associated with creating and joining processes.  Try something more time consuming and you'll notice the 20% rise to a more "expected" amount.

Also, if your bottleneck is the CPU isn't able to run multiple processes (shouldn't really happen nowadays with the dual/quad core cpus), you might not even notice a speed boost, since they're still being run serially at the hardware level.

Comment: I doubt it is the case that CPU isn't able to run multiple processes. I'm not limited by CPUs or other resources. Question: Where am I joining the processes? I thought the code I'm running as basically treating p1 and p2 indenpendently (as it should since every loop passing is unrelated)

Comment: Also, it'd be great if you could point me to something that would speed things up more... I've been searchign with no clear avail.

Comment: @user1727876 you may not be joining the processes then, but even spawning processes is costly.  Could you put up the code for `myfunc`?